# What is different between encoding and font?

Tags: encoding, fonts, language-agnostic

Encoding is maping that gives characters or symbols a unique value.

If a character is not present in encoding no matter what font you use it won't display correct fonts
Like Lucida console, arial or terminal

But problem is terminal font is showing line draw characters but other font is not showing line draw characters

My question is why terminal is behaving different to other font

Plz note
Windows 7 
Locale English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the impatient, the relevant link is at the bottom of this answer.

> Encoding is maping that gives characters or symbols a unique value.

No, that are the specifics of a character-set, which maps certain characters to code points (using the Unicode terminology). Lets ignore the above for now.

> If a character is not present in encoding no matter what font you use it won't display correct fonts Like Lucida console, arial or terminal

Font formats map Unicode code points to glyphs. Not all code points may be mapped for specific fonts - somebody has to create all these symbols. Again, lets ignore this.

Not all binary encodings may map to code points within a certain character set; this is possibly what you mean.

> But problem is terminal font is showing line draw characters but other font is not showing line draw characters

Your terminal seems to operate on a different character set, probably the "OEM" or "IBM PC" character set instead of a Unicode compliant character set or Windows-1252 / ISO 8859-1 / Latin.

If it is the latter than you are out of luck unless you can set your output-terminal to another character set, as Windows-1252 doesn't support the box drawing characters at all.

Solutions:

- If possible try and set the output to OEM / IBM PC character set.
- If it is Unicode you can try and convert the output to Unicode: read it in (decode it) using the OEM character set and then re-encode it using the [box drawing subset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

Comment: I think the 'Terminal Font' is different compared to other fonts because it is rastor bitmap format, its old and designed for the terminal.  when I try to print line draw the character using codepage 437, then no matter what font I use, it displays line draw character, so there seems to be either similarity between code 437 and terminal

Comment: Sounds like the IBM "OEM" font to me. That was used to draw textual "Windows" and stuff.